# MYSQL SELECT: How to get an additional column that indicates whether the first or the second condition in a WHERE clause was met?

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

How can I add a boolean column to a `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause and to conditions combined with an `OR` that is 1 if the first condition was met and 0 if the second and not the first condition was met?

As an example take the following table `t` with integer columns:

```
+----+---+---+
| id | a | b |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 2 | 3 |
|  2 | 3 | 2 |
|  3 | 5 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
```

When I execute the statement `SELECT * FROM t WHERE a<b OR b+1=a;` I get:

```
+----+---+---+
| id | a | b |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 2 | 3 |
|  2 | 3 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
```

And what I want is an additional column, say `cond`, like

```
+----+---+---+------+
| id | a | b | cond |
+----+---+---+------+
|  1 | 2 | 3 |    1 |
|  2 | 3 | 2 |    0 |
+----+---+---+------+
```

How can this be achieved in MySQL?

Comment: Why can't you make this determination in your application code?

Comment: @eggyal I think this could be also done somehow but 1. It is probably much slower (PHP) and 2. It is not so easy to determine this from the final output because in my real problem, the conditions involve another table and WHERE EXISTS statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
SELECT id, a, b, IF(a<b, 1,0) as cond
FROM t
WHERE a<b OR b+1=a;
```

Comment: You could even do `SELECT id, a, b, a<b AS cond` (because MySQL does not have real boolean types, and represents true as 1 and false as 0).

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a case statement in your select clause.

```
SELECT id, a, b, 
 CASE WHEN a<b THEN 1
      WHEN b+1=a THEN 0
 END x
FROM t WHERE a<b OR b+1=a
```

Comment: I see this as more cryptic.  The "else" clause is missing in the `CASE`.  But after some thought, I realize that the row won't be selected, so the `NULL` will not show.